# Linq Return Filtered Children

Tags: c#, linq, collections, filter

I'm having a 'duh' moment where this seems like it should be straight forward, but I can't seem to get it right.  I have a simple collection:

```
Category Name
   ---> List<Category>  (Children of this category)
```

I want the user to be able to filter based on Category.Name while maintaining the hierarchy.  So for example.

```
My Category
  ---> Category.Name, "ABC"
  ---> Category.Name, "123"
  ---> Category.Name, "CDE"
```

If the user types C, the filter should return

```
My Category
  ---> Category.Name, "ABC"
  ---> Category.Name, "CDE"
```

My attempt thus far has been

```
var v = vm.CategoryList
        .Where(p => p.CategoryItems.Any(q => q.Name.Contains(SearchText)));
```

This will filter and give me back all Category Names that contain category items which match the filter, but I still get the entire child category list, unfiltered.  What am I missing?

Comment: I was representing child records.  This is a tree, but it's only one level deep.

Comment: Oh. I thought "ABC" ---> "123" ---> "CDE" meant a two level deep tree.

Comment: what's the type of vm, vm.CategoryList and p.CategoryItems?  Looks like q is your Category, so CategoryItems would be an `IEnumerable<Category>`, but then, what's that it contains a member `CategoryItems` which is of this type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `Select` and return a filtered child list, like this:

```
var v = vm.CategoryList
          .Select(p => new { p.CategoryName, CategoryItems = p.CategoryItems.Where(q => q.Name.Contains(SearchText)))
          .Where(p => p.CategoryItems.Any()));
```

Comment: I think he needs a solution that will search down the hierarchy N levels, e.g. it has to be recursive

Comment: Some syntax errors, but I got the gist and this is what I was looking for. Thank you. Proper syntax is: var v = vm.CategoryList.Select(p => new { p.CategoryName, Items = p.CategoryItems.Where(q => q.Name.Contains(SearchText)).Where(a => a.CategoryName.Any()) } )

Comment: You want to write `.Where(a => a.CategoryItems.Any())` (not `Name`)