# LINQ Method that returns set based on filtered sub-set

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables.  1 has entity's, 1 per row.  Another is simply a mapping table of my EntitiesID and EmployeeID.  I am trying to write a LINQ method that returns all Entities from the First Table where the EntityID is in the mapping table that is filtered by the EmployeeID.

Simplified Table Structure Example
`TaskTable: ID, Description, Status`
`TaskViewTable: ID, TaskID, EmployeeID`

So I want to return all Rows from TaskTable where the ID is in a SubQuery results of TaskViewTable based on EmployeeID.

Any help on doing this in LINQ?  I have a 1 to Many set up between the two tables as well.  I know there are similar questions am maybe I'm dense but they didn't seem to apply completely to what I was asking.(e.g. [Linq Return Filtered Children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860192/linq-return-filtered-children))

Sorry forgot to show what I have so far:

```
IQueryable<tblTask> tTask=context.GetTable<tblTask>();
return tTask.Where(t => t.tblTasksViews.Where(v => v.EmployeeID == empID))
```

It, however, does not like my `where`with an `unkown method Where(?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var tasks = tTask.Where(t => 
    tTaskView.Where(v => v.ID == empId).Select(v => v.TaskId).Contains(t.ID));
```

You could break up the above into two sections:

```
//1.) Get all task views for the employeeID and only select the mapped TaskId
var taskViews = tTaskView.Where(v => v.ID == empId).Select(v => v.TaskId); //taskViews = IEnumerable<int>

//2.) Then get all tasks from the filtered task ids  
var tasks = tTask.Where(t => taskViews.Contains(t.ID));
```

**UPDATE**

```
//3.) Project filtered results into IEnumerable<Task>
return tasks.Select(t => new Task() 
{ 
    ID = t.ID, 
    ActionableID = t.ActionableID, 
    StatusID = t.StatusID, 
    TypeID = t.TypeID, 
    Description = t.Description 
});
```

You can, of course, string everything into a nice one-liner:

```
public List<Task> GetTasks(int empId) 
{
    return tTask
        .Where(t => tTaskView.Where(v => v.ID == empId).Select(v => v.TaskId).Contains(t.ID))
        .Select(t => new Task() 
        { 
            ID = t.ID, 
            ActionableID = t.ActionableID, 
            StatusID = t.StatusID, 
            TypeID = t.TypeID, 
            Description = t.Description 
        }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is there value in breaking it up beyond educational? Thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: Nope, no functional value as far as I'm aware. Breaking it up is usually just easier to read and understand. I prefer one-liners, though.

Comment: Okay, last clarification.  How do I specify the fields I want to Select?  i.e. I have a Task object I want to create and populate with this.  Normally I do something like this `.Select(t => new Task() {
                                       ID=t.ID,
                                       ActionableID=t.ActionableID,
                                       StatusID=t.StatusID,
                                       TypeID=t.TypeID,
                                       Description=t.Description,
                                       
                                   })`

Comment: You can still do that. Just slap that bit to the end of the last statement. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var query =
    from tt in TaskTable
    join tvt in TaskViewTable on tt.ID equals tvt.TaskID into xs
    where xs.Any(z => z.EmployeeID == empID)
    select tt;
```

Comment: How does the EmpID factor into this.  It's late and I am probably being dense but don't I need a where on the TaskViewTable for `tvt.EmpID == EmpID`(passed in param?

Comment: For example maybe this `where xs.Any(z => z.EmployeeID == empID)` would accomplish what I want?

Comment: From your description of the tables it didn't sound like `EmployeeID` fitted in to your table. However, you are right with your change to my `.Any()` call. I'll edit my answer.